# Function AFTER authentication and BEFORE view (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to get settings from the database and put them in the config,
my function need the user id so it can bring his settings only,
in the service provider ( boot function ) there is no authentication yet, can you please advise me to the right place to run my function, please note that I need it to run before the view get rendered because there are settings for the layout inside it, this is my function :

```
// public static becouse it's inside Class//
public static function getAppSettings(){
        if (!config('settings') && Auth::check()) {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $settings = AppSettings::where('user_id', $user_id)->get()->all();
            $settings = Cache::remember('settings', 60, function () use ($settings) {
                // Laravel >= 5.2, use 'lists' instead of 'pluck' for Laravel <= 5.1
                return $settings->pluck('value', 'key')->all();
            });
            config()->set('settings', $settings);
        }else{
            // this is for testing//
            dd('no');
        }
    }
```

**without the auth, it can work** inside the service provider ( boot function ) but it will bring all settings for all the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create middleware for this.Middleware calls after routes and before controller

```
php artisan make:middleware Settings
```

This will create below class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Settings
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
      // exicute your logic here
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

You can call your method inside `handle` and before next
You can read more about this in
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware